# Deploying Django app to Azure successful but shows the default django page, not my app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I checked to see if my files exist in wwwroot and this is what it showed:

[image]

I don't know how to get my files here.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows plan after deployed to azure you need to git `clone` your repo after you've initialized your local Git repo on the Azure Web App.

After created the Web app in azure you need to set a ***continuous deployment***.

Clone your deployed web app by using the url

```
git clone <your_url_convert_to_clone>
```

Your every change, `git add`., `git commit`, and `git push` them back to the repo in Azure to see your changes there.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32797857/15997690)

If you are using linux app service please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57346741/django-web-app-is-successfully-deployed-on-azure-app-service-linux-but-can-only)